# rosmake , build problems

Tags: rosmake, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I installed diamondback ROS on my VIrtual Ubunti machine. Tried to build the beginner_tutorials package with rosmake but . I couldnt errors occurred. I got something like this:

zeus@zeus-laptop:~/ros_tutor/beginner_tutorials$ rosmake beginner_tutorials
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['beginner_tutorials']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/zeus/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120503-192420
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['beginner_tutorials'] to:
['beginner_tutorials']
[ rosmake ] Checking rosdeps compliance for packages beginner_tutorials.  This may take a few seconds.
[ rosmake ] rosdep check passed all system dependencies in packages
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslib ROS_NOBUILD in package roslib
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< std_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package std_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosgraph_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosgraph_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbuild ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbuild
No Makefile in package rosbuild
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslang ROS_NOBUILD in package roslang
No Makefile in package roslang
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rospy ROS_NOBUILD in package rospy
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> cpp_common [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< cpp_common ROS_NOBUILD in package cpp_common
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp_traits [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp_traits ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_traits
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rostime [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rostime ROS_NOBUILD in package rostime
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp_serialization [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp_serialization ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_serialization
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> xmlrpcpp [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< xmlrpcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package xmlrpcpp
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosconsole ROS_NOBUILD in package rosconsole
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> beginner_tutorials [ make ]
[ rosmake ] All 16 lineseginner_tutorials: 2.4 sec ] [ 1 Active 14/15 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mkdir -p bin
cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
CMake Error at build/CMakeFiles/CMakeSystem.cmake:1 (INCLUDE):
include could not find load file:

```
  /opt/ros/cturtle/ros/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake
```

Call Stack (most recent call first):

### [rosbuild] Building package beginner_tutorials
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/rospy/cmake/rospy.cmake
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/roslisp/cmake/roslisp.cmake
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/cmake/roscpp.cmake
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

[ rosmake ] Output from build of package beginner_tutorials written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/zeus/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120503-192420/beginner_tutorials/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< beginner_tutorials [FAIL] [ 2.50 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package beginner_tutorials.
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:
[ rosmake ] Built 15 packages with 1 failures.
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
[ rosmake ] /home/zeus/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120503-192420
zeus@zeus-laptop:~/ros_tutor/beginner_tutorials$

Can you help me please? also roscore does not initialize. Any advice?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33214/rosmake-,-build-problems/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2012-05-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems like something in your configuration is pointing to a cturtle installation of ROS. Did you have a previous installation of cturtle on your machine? Or do you have a parallel cturtle-installation somewhere?

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) on 2012-05-03**:
Btw. why do you want to use diamondback? Is ROS Electric no option for you?